# Hardware suggestion for recording DVI on mac with unknown frame rate

Tags: hardware, video-recording, screen-casting

I am trying to record a screen recording from a medical imaging display (a box with output ports that can be plugged into a monitor), and I am unsure what is the best hardware to have the best chance at recording the video stream.

**Specs**

- Video resolution: 1080i
- Video frame rate: unknown (proprietary to company) to  but likely not 29.97, 30, 59.94, or 60 fps
- Ports to record from: DVI or SDI
- Computer to record to: macbook pro early 2013 (Thunderbolt or HDMI ports will support this amount of data, but write to disk speed is likely not fast enough to support writing uncompressed video)
- Cost: Lowest possible...

**What I've tried**
I bought the [Blackmagic Ultrastudio Mini Recorder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009D91314) and tried to record via the SDI port of the imaging display. However, one of the only parameters you can change is the video frame rate from a short list. None of these seemed to match the frame rate of the imaging system. The manufacturer of the imaging display said this value is proprietary.

**Question**

 What hardware should I look at to be able to record this video stream with unknown frame rate.

Comment: Note that what you are trying to do may not even be possible.  There is a high degree of likelihood that they are using the content protection mechanisms that DVI supports to prevent unauthorized usage and protect the PHI that is being displayed.  If they are doing that, then you will not be able to capture the data no matter what you hook up to it.  Can you hook any monitor of your choice up to it or does it have to be theirs?

Comment: Thanks, AJ. This was a really great idea -- the arbitrary computer monitor worked, so I think there's no protection mechanism in place.